# Можно ли подружить Qt и SAPI?

Tags: qt, visual-studio, microsoft-speech-sdk

Всем привет!

Кому-нибудь удавалось использовать SAPI с Qt?

Если я правильно понимаю, Qt можно запустить на компиляторе MinGW или MSVC. MinGW ставится без проблем и работает все из коробки, но проблема в том, что там нет ATL, который нужен для работы с SAPI.

Если же я хочу запустить с MSVC, мне нужно отдельно иметь компилятор, который не идет вместе со сборкой Qt, еще отдельно дебаггер. В идеале придется поставить Visual Studio рядом с Qt.

И это все только ради того, чтобы научить Qt'шную программу "говорить".

Есть ли способы менее извращенные?

Comment: Если надо чтобы программа разговаривала, посмотрите в сторону QtSpeech https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qtspeech-hello-speak-example.html